# Do all nodes communicate using the JSON RPC protocol?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

I'm reading through the JSON RPC Doc now on Github here: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#net_version

I assumed that this is the default communication protocol between any two nodes, and between a node and a client (such as web3).

But then it mentioned how to start geth and the c++ node in "RPC mode". So is RPC not the default communication mode?

- If not, how else does node-to-node communication happen?
- If so, what are use cases for starting a node NOT in rpc mode?

Answer (score 3):

The connection between ethereum nodes is using the [ÐΞVp2p Wire Protocol](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/%C3%90%CE%9EVp2p-Wire-Protocol).

Disabling the RPC interface for your ethereum node is a security consideration, especially if you have an internet facing node. [This case](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/3ird55/holy_shit_my_eth_accounts_been_hacked/) is just one of many cases where people had their ETH stolen through the RPC interface. The RPC interface is for user interaction, not for p2p.

Answer (score 1):

I can partially answer, especially since you ask about c++ node and connecting to client.

When you start `eth`, the default communication with client (e.g., mist or geth console) is through `ipc` (inter-process communication), not `rpc`. To enable `rpc` you need to start `eth` with `-j` flag. By default `rpc` is disabled in cpp-ethereum node. I think its for security reasons.

Conections with other nodes is using `p2p` and `boost/asio`. I dont know too much about it, but i think its totally different type of communication than just rpc.